# Optimize query with nested inner query and case statements

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization, sql-server-2017

I have below query written by someone(Database is Microsoft SQL server 2017). I do not have access to database to create indexes etc., So only way I can do is optimize below query as efficient as possible.

My query here is,

Can I use Case and WHEN in inner query as used in the below query? Also am currently trying to remove nested queries by using inner join.

Any other ideas will be appreciated for the below queries. I am not asking to give final optimized query, but asking suggestion specific to below query.

```
WITH   ChildPremiumCTE (COVER_PREMIUM_SET_ID,POLICY_ID, ADDRESS_ID, STATUS_CODE,COVER_PREMIUM_MODEL_ID, SUB_PRODUCT_REF
, COVER_PREMIUM_MODEL_REF, DESCRIPTION, PREMIUM_LEVEL_CODE
, PREMIUM_PAYABLE, PREMIUM_DUE, COMMISSION_GST, COMMISSION, COMMISSION_TOTAL,TERRORISM_GST
, TERRORISM_RI, STAMP_DUTY, GST, FSL
, MODIFIED_PREMIUM,  TECHNICAL_PREMIUM, BASE_PREMIUM
, PREMIUM_PAYABLE_TERM, PREMIUM_DUE_TERM, COMMISSION_GST_TERM
, COMMISSION_TERM, COMMISSION_TOTAL_TERM, TERRORISM_GST_TERM
, TERRORISM_RI_TERM, STAMP_DUTY_TERM,  GST_TERM, FSL_TERM
, MODIFIED_PREMIUM_TERM,  TECHNICAL_PREMIUM_TERM,  BASE_PREMIUM_TERM
, PREMIUM_PAYABLE_ANNUALISED, PREMIUM_DUE_ANNUALISED, COMMISSION_GST_ANNUALISED
, COMMISSION_ANNUALISED, COMMISSION_TOTAL_ANNUALISED, TERRORISM_GST_ANNUALISED
, TERRORISM_RI_ANNUALISED,  STAMP_DUTY_ANNUALISED, GST_ANNUALISED
, FSL_ANNUALISED,  MODIFIED_PREMIUM_ANNUALISED,  TECHNICAL_PREMIUM_ANNUALISED
, BASE_PREMIUM_ANNUALISED)
AS (SELECT CPP.COVER_PREMIUM_SET_ID
, CPS.POLICY_ID
, CASE WHEN CPS.PREMIUM_LEVEL_CODE = 'PREMITEM' THEN SS.ADDRESS_ID  ELSE AD.ADDRESS_ID END ADDRESS_ID
, SS.STATUS_CODE
, COALESCE(CPM.COVER_PREMIUM_MODEL_ID, 0) COVER_PREMIUM_MODEL_ID
, CASE WHEN CPS.PREMIUM_LEVEL_CODE = 'POLSUM' THEN 'POLICY_SUMMARY' 
  ELSE CASE WHEN CPS.PREMIUM_LEVEL_CODE = 'SITSUM' THEN 'SITUATION_SUMMARY' ELSE CPS.SUB_PRODUCT_REF END END SUB_PRODUCT_REF
, CPS.COVER_PREMIUM_MODEL_REF
, CPS.DESCRIPTION
, CPS.PREMIUM_LEVEL_CODE
, MAX(CASE WHEN CPP.PREMIUM_MODEL_PART_REF = 'PREMIUM_PAYABLE' THEN CPP.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT END) PREMIUM_PAYABLE 
, MAX(CASE WHEN CPP.PREMIUM_MODEL_PART_REF = 'PREMIUM_DUE' THEN CPP.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT END) PREMIUM_DUE 
, MAX(CASE WHEN CPP.PREMIUM_MODEL_PART_REF = 'COMMISSION_GST' THEN CPP.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT END) COMMISSION_GST 
, MAX(CASE WHEN CPP.PREMIUM_MODEL_PART_REF = 'COMMISSION' THEN CPP.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT END) COMMISSION 
, MAX(CASE WHEN CPP.PREMIUM_MODEL_PART_REF = 'COMMISSION_TOTAL' THEN CPP.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT END) COMMISSION_TOTAL 
, MAX(CASE WHEN CPP.PREMIUM_MODEL_PART_REF = 'TERRORISM_GST' THEN CPP.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT END) TERRORISM_GST 
, MAX(CASE WHEN CPP.PREMIUM_MODEL_PART_REF = 'TERRORISM_RI' THEN CPP.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT END) TERRORISM_RI 
, MAX(CASE WHEN CPP.PREMIUM_MODEL_PART_REF = 'STAMP_DUTY' THEN CPP.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT END) STAMP_DUTY 
, MAX(CASE WHEN CPP.PREMIUM_MODEL_PART_REF = 'GST' THEN CPP.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT END) GST 
, MAX(CASE WHEN CPP.PREMIUM_MODEL_PART_REF = 'FSL' THEN CPP.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT END) FSL 
, MAX(CASE WHEN CPP.PREMIUM_MODEL_PART_REF = 'MODIFIED_PREMIUM' THEN CPP.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT END) MODIFIED_PREMIUM 
, MAX(CASE WHEN CPP.PREMIUM_MODEL_PART_REF = 'TECHNICAL_PREMIUM' THEN CPP.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT END) TECHNICAL_PREMIUM 
, MAX(CASE WHEN CPP.PREMIUM_MODEL_PART_REF = 'BASE_PREMIUM' THEN CPP.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT END) BASE_PREMIUM 
, MAX(CASE WHEN CPP.PREMIUM_MODEL_PART_REF = 'PREMIUM_PAYABLE' THEN CPP.TERM_AMOUNT END) PREMIUM_PAYABLE_TERM 
, MAX(CASE WHEN CPP.PREMIUM_MODEL_PART_REF = 'PREMIUM_DUE' THEN CPP.TERM_AMOUNT END) PREMIUM_DUE_TERM
, MAX(CASE WHEN CPP.PREMIUM_MODEL_PART_REF = 'COMMISSION_GST' THEN CPP.TERM_AMOUNT END) COMMISSION_GST_TERM 
, MAX(CASE WHEN CPP.PREMIUM_MODEL_PART_REF = 'COMMISSION' THEN CPP.TERM_AMOUNT END) COMMISSION_TERM 
, MAX(CASE WHEN CPP.PREMIUM_MODEL_PART_REF = 'COMMISSION_TOTAL' THEN CPP.TERM_AMOUNT END) COMMISSION_TOTAL_TERM 
, MAX(CASE WHEN CPP.PREMIUM_MODEL_PART_REF = 'TERRORISM_GST' THEN CPP.TERM_AMOUNT END) TERRORISM_GST_TERM 
, MAX(CASE WHEN CPP.PREMIUM_MODEL_PART_REF = 'TERRORISM_RI' THEN CPP.TERM_AMOUNT END) TERRORISM_RI_TERM 
, MAX(CASE WHEN CPP.PREMIUM_MODEL_PART_REF = 'STAMP_DUTY' THEN CPP.TERM_AMOUNT END) STAMP_DUTY_TERM 
, MAX(CASE WHEN CPP.PREMIUM_MODEL_PART_REF = 'GST' THEN CPP.TERM_AMOUNT END) GST_TERM 
, MAX(CASE WHEN CPP.PREMIUM_MODEL_PART_REF = 'FSL' THEN CPP.TERM_AMOUNT END) FSL_TERM 
, MAX(CASE WHEN CPP.PREMIUM_MODEL_PART_REF = 'MODIFIED_PREMIUM' THEN CPP.TERM_AMOUNT END) MODIFIED_PREMIUM_TERM
, MAX(CASE WHEN CPP.PREMIUM_MODEL_PART_REF = 'TECHNICAL_PREMIUM' THEN CPP.TERM_AMOUNT END) TECHNICAL_PREMIUM_TERM 
, MAX(CASE WHEN CPP.PREMIUM_MODEL_PART_REF = 'BASE_PREMIUM' THEN CPP.TERM_AMOUNT END) BASE_PREMIUM_TERM 
, MAX(CASE WHEN CPP.PREMIUM_MODEL_PART_REF = 'PREMIUM_PAYABLE' THEN CPP.FUTURE_ANNUALISED_AMOUNT END) PREMIUM_PAYABLE_ANNUALISED 
, MAX(CASE WHEN CPP.PREMIUM_MODEL_PART_REF = 'PREMIUM_DUE' THEN CPP.FUTURE_ANNUALISED_AMOUNT END) PREMIUM_DUE_ANNUALISED 
, MAX(CASE WHEN CPP.PREMIUM_MODEL_PART_REF = 'COMMISSION_GST' THEN CPP.FUTURE_ANNUALISED_AMOUNT END) COMMISSION_GST_ANNUALISED 
, MAX(CASE WHEN CPP.PREMIUM_MODEL_PART_REF = 'COMMISSION' THEN CPP.FUTURE_ANNUALISED_AMOUNT END) COMMISSION_ANNUALISED 
, MAX(CASE WHEN CPP.PREMIUM_MODEL_PART_REF = 'COMMISSION_TOTAL' THEN CPP.FUTURE_ANNUALISED_AMOUNT END) COMMISSION_TOTAL_ANNUALISED 
, MAX(CASE WHEN CPP.PREMIUM_MODEL_PART_REF = 'TERRORISM_GST' THEN CPP.FUTURE_ANNUALISED_AMOUNT END) TERRORISM_GST_ANNUALISED 
, MAX(CASE WHEN CPP.PREMIUM_MODEL_PART_REF = 'TERRORISM_RI' THEN CPP.FUTURE_ANNUALISED_AMOUNT END) TERRORISM_RI_ANNUALISED 
, MAX(CASE WHEN CPP.PREMIUM_MODEL_PART_REF = 'STAMP_DUTY' THEN CPP.FUTURE_ANNUALISED_AMOUNT END) STAMP_DUTY_ANNUALISED 
, MAX(CASE WHEN CPP.PREMIUM_MODEL_PART_REF = 'GST' THEN CPP.FUTURE_ANNUALISED_AMOUNT END) GST_ANNUALISED 
, MAX(CASE WHEN CPP.PREMIUM_MODEL_PART_REF = 'FSL' THEN CPP.FUTURE_ANNUALISED_AMOUNT END) FSL_ANNUALISED 
, MAX(CASE WHEN CPP.PREMIUM_MODEL_PART_REF = 'MODIFIED_PREMIUM' THEN CPP.FUTURE_ANNUALISED_AMOUNT END) MODIFIED_PREMIUM_ANNUALISED 
, MAX(CASE WHEN CPP.PREMIUM_MODEL_PART_REF = 'TECHNICAL_PREMIUM' THEN CPP.FUTURE_ANNUALISED_AMOUNT END) TECHNICAL_PREMIUM_ANNUALISED 
, MAX(CASE WHEN CPP.PREMIUM_MODEL_PART_REF = 'BASE_PREMIUM' THEN CPP.FUTURE_ANNUALISED_AMOUNT END) BASE_PREMIUM_ANNUALISED
FROM COVER_PREMIUM_SET As CPS 
LEFT JOIN SITUATION_SECTION As SS ON CPS.POLICY_ID = SS.POLICY_ID 
     AND CPS.SITUATION_SECTION_REF = SS.SITUATION_SECTION_REF       
LEFT JOIN COVER_PREMIUM_PART As CPP ON CPS.COVER_PREMIUM_SET_ID = CPP.COVER_PREMIUM_SET_ID 
LEFT JOIN ADDRESS As AD ON CPS.POLICY_ID = AD.POLICY_ID 
     AND AD.ADDRESS_REF = CPS.ENTITY_INSTANCE_REF 
     AND CPS.PREMIUM_LEVEL_CODE IN ('SITSUM', 'SUBPRODSUM') 
LEFT JOIN COVER_PREMIUM_MODEL As CPM ON CPS.COVER_PREMIUM_MODEL_REF = CPM.COVER_PREMIUM_MODEL_REF
GROUP BY CPP.COVER_PREMIUM_SET_ID,
CPS.POLICY_ID,
CPS.DESCRIPTION,
CPS.PREMIUM_LEVEL_CODE,
CPS.COVER_PREMIUM_MODEL_REF,
CPS.SUB_PRODUCT_REF,
CPM.COVER_PREMIUM_MODEL_ID,
SS.SITUATION_SECTION_ID,
SS.ADDRESS_ID,
SS.STATUS_CODE,
CPS.ENTITY_INSTANCE_REF,
AD.ADDRESS_ID )

select * from (SELECT
0 AS COVER_PREMIUM_SET_ID
, a1.POLICY_ID
, a1.ADDRESS_ID
, a1.STATUS_CODE
, CPM_CHILD.PARENT_ID AS COVER_PREMIUM_MODEL_ID
, CASE WHEN CPM.PREMIUM_LEVEL_CODE = 'POLSUM' THEN 'POLICY_SUMMARY' 
  ELSE CASE WHEN CPM.PREMIUM_LEVEL_CODE = 'SITSUM' THEN 'SITUATION_SUMMARY' ELSE a1.SUB_PRODUCT_REF END END SUB_PRODUCT_REF
, CPM.COVER_PREMIUM_MODEL_REF
, CPM.NAME AS Description
, CPM.PREMIUM_LEVEL_CODE AS PREMIUM_LEVEL_CODE
, sum(a1.PREMIUM_PAYABLE) PREMIUM_PAYABLE
, sum(a1.PREMIUM_DUE) PREMIUM_DUE
, sum(a1.COMMISSION_GST) COMMISSION_GST
, sum(a1.COMMISSION) COMMISSION
, sum(a1.COMMISSION_TOTAL) COMMISSION_TOTAL,sum(a1.TERRORISM_GST) TERRORISM_GST
, sum(a1.TERRORISM_RI) TERRORISM_RI, sum(a1.STAMP_DUTY) STAMP_DUTY,sum(a1.GST ) GST, sum(a1.FSL ) FSL
, sum(a1.MODIFIED_PREMIUM ) MODIFIED_PREMIUM,  sum(a1.TECHNICAL_PREMIUM ) TECHNICAL_PREMIUM, sum(a1.BASE_PREMIUM ) BASE_PREMIUM
, sum(a1.PREMIUM_PAYABLE_TERM) PREMIUM_PAYABLE_TERM, sum(a1.PREMIUM_DUE_TERM ) PREMIUM_DUE_TERM
, sum(a1.COMMISSION_GST_TERM ) COMMISSION_GST_TERM,  sum(a1.COMMISSION_TERM ) COMMISSION_TERM
, sum(a1.COMMISSION_TOTAL_TERM ) COMMISSION_TOTAL_TERM, sum(a1.TERRORISM_GST_TERM ) TERRORISM_GST_TERM
, sum(a1.TERRORISM_RI_TERM ) TERRORISM_RI_TERM, sum(a1.STAMP_DUTY_TERM ) STAMP_DUTY_TERM
, sum(a1.GST_TERM ) GST_TERM, sum(a1.FSL_TERM ) FSL_TERM, sum(a1.MODIFIED_PREMIUM_TERM ) MODIFIED_PREMIUM_TERM
, sum(a1.TECHNICAL_PREMIUM_TERM ) TECHNICAL_PREMIUM_TERM,  sum(a1.BASE_PREMIUM_TERM ) BASE_PREMIUM_TERM
, sum(a1.PREMIUM_PAYABLE_ANNUALISED) PREMIUM_PAYABLE_ANNUALISED, sum(a1.PREMIUM_DUE_ANNUALISED ) PREMIUM_DUE_ANNUALISED
, sum(a1.COMMISSION_GST_ANNUALISED ) COMMISSION_GST_ANNUALISED,  sum(a1. COMMISSION_ANNUALISED ) COMMISSION_ANNUALISED
, sum(a1. COMMISSION_TOTAL_ANNUALISED ) COMMISSION_TOTAL_ANNUALISED, sum(a1.TERRORISM_GST_ANNUALISED ) TERRORISM_GST_ANNUALISED
, sum(a1.TERRORISM_RI_ANNUALISED ) TERRORISM_RI_ANNUALISED,  sum(a1.STAMP_DUTY_ANNUALISED ) STAMP_DUTY_ANNUALISED
, sum(a1.GST_ANNUALISED ) GST_ANNUALISED, sum(a1.FSL_ANNUALISED ) FSL_ANNUALISED
,  sum(a1.MODIFIED_PREMIUM_ANNUALISED ) MODIFIED_PREMIUM_ANNUALISED
, sum(a1.TECHNICAL_PREMIUM_ANNUALISED ) TECHNICAL_PREMIUM_ANNUALISED
, sum(a1.BASE_PREMIUM_ANNUALISED) BASE_PREMIUM_ANNUALISED

FROM COVER_PREMIUM_MODEL CPM,
COVER_PREMIUM_MODEL CPM_CHILD,
ChildPremiumCTE a1
WHERE
                    CPM.PREMIUM_LEVEL_CODE = 'PREMRLUP' 
                    AND CPM_CHILD.PARENT_ID = CPM.COVER_PREMIUM_MODEL_ID 
                    AND CPM_CHILD.COVER_PREMIUM_MODEL_REF = a1.COVER_PREMIUM_MODEL_REF
            GROUP BY
                a1.POLICY_ID,
                a1.ADDRESS_ID,
                CPM_CHILD.PARENT_ID,
                CPM.NAME,
                CPM.PREMIUM_LEVEL_CODE,
                a1.SUB_PRODUCT_REF,
                CPM.COVER_PREMIUM_MODEL_REF,
                a1.STATUS_CODE 
 UNION ALL
 select * from  ChildPremiumCTE) CoverPremium where CoverPremium.POLICY_ID = 77780029
```

So far what I have improved is,

- Made union to union all
- Trying to convert subqueries into where clause
- built in functions like MAX, SUM to like string literal

Comment: Times like this I'm glad that a codeblock only shows part of a super big query... Improvement? Start with writing thing like `FROM uat_cod_helo.COVER_PREMIUM_MODEL CPM
            ,uat_cod_helo.COVER_PREMIUM_MODEL CPM_CHILD
            ,uat_cod_helo.SUB_PRODUCT SP
            ,PRODUCT P
            ,PRODUCT_SUB_PRODUCT PSP` in the proper `JOIN` syntax.  Less risk on accidental cartesian product joins. Comma joins are so last century.

Comment: And using a few [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql)'s might help also.

Comment: Can you use temp tables? I have noticed some situations where a temp table performs better than a CTE, usually with larger data sets. Both CTEs and Temp Tables would help with readability

Comment: I would look at the sub-selects in the columns. That can be a very expensive operation for a select to occur on every row.

Comment: Nobody can help you here fix the performance. We don't have the table structures or anything at all to work with. But I would highly recommend using some aliases in your queries. And time to start using ANSI-92 style joins....they have been around now for more than 30 years. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins And with everything in all caps and only sort of formatted this is impossible to read.

Comment: which tables contain PREMIUM_MODEL_PART_REF & TRANSACTION_AMOUNT ?

Comment: PREMIUM_MODEL_PART_REF and TRANSACTION_AMOUNT belong to which table ?

Comment: @SeanLange i am using around 5 tables. all has big number of columns. Not sure how to attach schema here.

Comment: @KumarHarsh both belong to same table 'COVER_PREMIUM_PART'

Comment: @Iptr both belong to same table 'COVER_PREMIUM_PART'

Comment: Your cte is pulling every row from the table but then you filter that only a certain POLICY_ID in your final query. I find this incredibly difficult to read because absolutely everything is in all caps. And the lack of aliases is adding hundreds of extra characters. At the very least posting an execution plan would help a LOT. You can upload it here. https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ Make sure it is the actual execution plan, not the estimate.

Answer (score 2):

First suggestion is same as @LukStorms.Also always use alias of table and prefix them in column so that it is very easy to understand and debug.

> Can I use Case and WHEN in inner query as used in the below query?

Everything has cost.It seem that in this case cost is negligible.

> Any other ideas will be appreciated for the below queries. I am not
>   asking to give final optimized query, but asking suggestion specific
>   to below query.

1. `GROUP BY` on All column is always bad idea.First Using CTE or #Temp table
   write Group By query using only require table and Group By on Key column only.

Suppose you need some other column also which is not part of aggregate or Group By,then no problem don't try to use that column here.
Join the same table in main query to get those columns which is not part of aggregate.

Then in Main query again join that CTE or temp table with other table.

This is how you should design your query .

> `PREMIUM_MODEL_PART_REF and TRANSACTION_AMOUNT belong to which table ?`

Table `COVER_PREMIUM_MODEL` are use 3 times in query.Put the require data of `COVER_PREMIUM_MODEL` on `#temp table` .There must be some common result in all three join.

Excerpt

```
select * from (Select * blah blah
UNION ALL
 select * from     ChildPremiumCTE) a2 where a2.POLICY_ID = 77780029
```

WHY use `where POLICY_ID = 77780029` in the end ?
This way first so many rows will be process in inner query then finally reduce to `POLICY_ID = 77780029`.

So WHY not use `POLICY_ID = 77780029` in inner query somewhere in the first place.

> built in functions like MAX, SUM to like string literal

It depend what  type of `UDF` it is and what you have written in it.
In short `UDF` are notoriously Bad Perform-ant most of the time.

It do not appear to be that `MAX, SUM` need `UDF`.

Comment: both belong to same table 'COVER_PREMIUM_PART'